# How can I create an AudioClip from an audio file in byte[]

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I have audio files (WAV and OGG) that are stored inside another data file ([some misc data...][flag indicating ogg and length][OGG file data][more misc data...]). I can extract the OGG and WAV file data into byte arrays easily enough. How do I convert the byte arrays to AudioClip objects? I don't want to decode all the audio myself or add extensions. I also need to do this cross platform. Speed is not really critical so a solution like writing the data to a temp file then using WWW to load it seems viable, but I don't know how to create a cross platform, sandbox safe, temp file, and I'm hoping there's a way to do this all in memory so I don't need to thrash the disk (but if I have to then so be it).

Comment: Hi ima, I am running into this same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. I'm sure it's possible but probably requires a plugin to be able to push the encoded data into the right place to then be decoded by the handler. I don't have the time to resolve that path.

Comment: Regarding OGG I guess you will need to use some kind of decoder. However, you can find a solution for the WAV scenario here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965193/1934546

Answer (score 0):

After extracting the file data into a float array - or converting the byte array into float array in your case, you can create an AudioClip instance using the static [Create](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.Create.html) function and fill that instance in by [SetData](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.SetData.html) function respectively.

Here is an example code doing the exact same thing you refer to:
[create AudioClip from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078254/create-audioclip-from-byte)

Comment: I thought the AudioClip SetData expected raw audio stream data, not encoded/compressed wav/ogg data...

Comment: I don't think this is possible as described, as all I have is a byte array, I don't know the channels, frequency, samples, etc. This would be shoving and encoded audio file into a memory space expecting raw audio samples.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably redundant, but you can use the implementation I published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965193/1934546) to create an `AudioClip` from a WAV PCM `byte[]`:

### PcmHeader

```
private readonly struct PcmHeader
{
    #region Public types & data

    public int    BitDepth         { get; }
    public int    AudioSampleSize  { get; }
    public int    AudioSampleCount { get; }
    public ushort Channels         { get; }
    public int    SampleRate       { get; }
    public int    AudioStartIndex  { get; }
    public int    ByteRate         { get; }
    public ushort BlockAlign       { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors & Finalizer

    private PcmHeader(int bitDepth,
        int               audioSize,
        int               audioStartIndex,
        ushort            channels,
        int               sampleRate,
        int               byteRate,
        ushort            blockAlign)
    {
        BitDepth       = bitDepth;
        _negativeDepth = Mathf.Pow(2f, BitDepth - 1f);
        _positiveDepth = _negativeDepth - 1f;

        AudioSampleSize  = bitDepth / 8;
        AudioSampleCount = Mathf.FloorToInt(audioSize / (float)AudioSampleSize);
        AudioStartIndex  = audioStartIndex;

        Channels   = channels;
        SampleRate = sampleRate;
        ByteRate   = byteRate;
        BlockAlign = blockAlign;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public static PcmHeader FromBytes(byte[] pcmBytes)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(pcmBytes);
        return FromStream(memoryStream);
    }

    public static PcmHeader FromStream(Stream pcmStream)
    {
        pcmStream.Position = SizeIndex;
        using BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(pcmStream);

        int    headerSize      = reader.ReadInt32();  // 16
        ushort audioFormatCode = reader.ReadUInt16(); // 20

        string audioFormat = GetAudioFormatFromCode(audioFormatCode);
        if (audioFormatCode != 1 && audioFormatCode == 65534)
        {
            // Only uncompressed PCM wav files are supported.
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(pcmStream),
                                                  $"Detected format code '{audioFormatCode}' {audioFormat}, but only PCM and WaveFormatExtensible uncompressed formats are currently supported.");
        }

        ushort channelCount = reader.ReadUInt16(); // 22
        int    sampleRate   = reader.ReadInt32();  // 24
        int    byteRate     = reader.ReadInt32();  // 28
        ushort blockAlign   = reader.ReadUInt16(); // 32
        ushort bitDepth     = reader.ReadUInt16(); //34

        pcmStream.Position = SizeIndex + headerSize + 2 * sizeof(int); // Header end index
        int audioSize = reader.ReadInt32();                            // Audio size index

        return new PcmHeader(bitDepth, audioSize, (int)pcmStream.Position, channelCount, sampleRate, byteRate, blockAlign); // audio start index
    }

    public float NormalizeSample(float rawSample)
    {
        float sampleDepth = rawSample < 0 ? _negativeDepth : _positiveDepth;
        return rawSample / sampleDepth;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private static string GetAudioFormatFromCode(ushort code)
    {
        switch (code)
        {
            case 1:     return "PCM";
            case 2:     return "ADPCM";
            case 3:     return "IEEE";
            case 7:     return "?-law";
            case 65534: return "WaveFormatExtensible";
            default:    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(code), code, "Unknown wav code format.");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private types & Data

    private const int SizeIndex = 16;

    private readonly float _positiveDepth;
    private readonly float _negativeDepth;

    #endregion
}
```

### PcmData

```
private readonly struct PcmData
{
    #region Public types & data

    public float[] Value      { get; }
    public int     Length     { get; }
    public int     Channels   { get; }
    public int     SampleRate { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors & Finalizer

    private PcmData(float[] value, int channels, int sampleRate)
    {
        Value      = value;
        Length     = value.Length;
        Channels   = channels;
        SampleRate = sampleRate;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public static PcmData FromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bytes));
        }

        PcmHeader pcmHeader = PcmHeader.FromBytes(bytes);
        if (pcmHeader.BitDepth != 16 && pcmHeader.BitDepth != 32 && pcmHeader.BitDepth != 8)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(pcmHeader.BitDepth), pcmHeader.BitDepth, "Supported values are: 8, 16, 32");
        }

        float[] samples = new float[pcmHeader.AudioSampleCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; ++i)
        {
            int   byteIndex = pcmHeader.AudioStartIndex + i * pcmHeader.AudioSampleSize;
            float rawSample;
            switch (pcmHeader.BitDepth)
            {
                case 8:
                    rawSample = bytes[byteIndex];
                    break;

                case 16:
                    rawSample = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, byteIndex);
                    break;

                case 32:
                    rawSample = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, byteIndex);
                    break;

                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(pcmHeader.BitDepth), pcmHeader.BitDepth, "Supported values are: 8, 16, 32");
            }

            samples[i] = pcmHeader.NormalizeSample(rawSample); // normalize sample between [-1f, 1f]
        }

        return new PcmData(samples, pcmHeader.Channels, pcmHeader.SampleRate);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

### Usage

```
public static AudioClip FromPcmBytes(byte[] bytes, string clipName = "pcm")
{
    clipName.ThrowIfNullOrWhitespace(nameof(clipName));
    var pcmData   = PcmData.FromBytes(bytes);
    var audioClip = AudioClip.Create(clipName, pcmData.Length, pcmData.Channels, pcmData.SampleRate, false);
    audioClip.SetData(pcmData.Value, 0);
    return audioClip;
}
```

Note that `AudioClip.Create` provides an overload with Read and SetPosition callbacks in case you need to work with a source `Stream` instead of a chunk of bytes.