# Converting mp3 byte array to float array to play with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, mp3, ros

So I'm currently trying to take audio from an external microphone (that's actually on a robot in this case) and stream it into Unity to be played in a scene. I'm fairly certain this audio is encoded in the mp3 format with a sample rate of 16000 Hz and a bitrate of 192 kHz.

I'm able to get this audio as a byte array (that seems to always be Little Endian) in Unity, and I'd like to convert  to a float array with each value ranging from -1.0f to +1.0f so that I can use AudioClip.SetData to play it in the Unity scene. My problem is that I'm so far unable to do this.

My first attempt was based on this StackOverflow answer: [create AudioClip from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078254/create-audioclip-from-byte)
which uses the following function for conversion:

```
private float[] ConvertByteToFloat(byte[] array) {
        float[] floatArr = new float[array.Length / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < floatArr.Length; i++) {
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
                Array.Reverse(array, i * 4, 4);
            }
            floatArr[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(array, i * 4) / 0x80000000;
        }
        return floatArr;
    }
```

I then invoked this like so:

```
scaledAudio = ConvertByteToFloat(audioData);
AudioClip audioClip = AudioClip.Create("RobotAudio", scaledAudio.Length, 1, 16000, false);
audioClip.SetData(scaledAudio, 0);
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(audioClip, robot.transform.position);
```

But the result was a lot of static, and on logging some outputs, I realized that I was getting a bunch of NaN's...

I read somewhere that mp3 audio could extracted using the `BitConverter.ToInt16()` function, so I changed the `ConvertByteToFloat` function accordingly like so:

```
private float[] ConvertByteToFloat16(byte[] array) {
            float[] floatArr = new float[array.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < floatArr.Length; i++) {
                if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
                    Array.Reverse(array, i * 2, 2);
                }
                floatArr[i] = (float) (BitConverter.ToInt16(array, i * 2) / 32767f);
            }
            return floatArr;
        }
```

[Note: the result is divided by 32767f because I read this is the maximum value that can occur and I want to scale it down to between -1.0f and 1.0f]

The numbers from this look much more promising. They are indeed all between -1.0f and 1.0f. But when I attempt to play the audio with Unity, all I hear is static.

The issue almost definitely seems to be in the conversion of the byte[] to the float[], but I could've made a mistake in setting the data or the player for the AudioClip or the AudioSource.

Any help/suggestions are MUCH appreciated!

[Additional resources: The byte[] that I got into unity comes from here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/blob/master/audio_capture/src/audio_capture.cpp
There is a related script that takes the data encoded by this capture program and plays it (https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/blob/master/audio_play/src/audio_play.cpp). This works just fine - so if I could replicate the decoding functionality of the audio_play script in that second link, it seems like I'll be good to go!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [file you linked](https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/blob/master/audio_capture/src/audio_capture.cpp), it says during the setup that it encodes the data as encoded mp3 format (line number on left).

```
21 >> // Need to encoding or publish raw wave data
22 >> ros::param::param<std::string>("~format", _format, "mp3");
```

This means you have two options.

## Export Wave format (Raw PCM) from your library

Change the output format from the C++ library to export a raw wave file format.

```
21 >> // Need to encoding or publish raw wave data
22 >> ros::param::param<std::string>("~format", _format, "wave");
```

Reading through the code if you change line 22's third constructor argument to *"wave"*, it will export the data as .wav format, and will therefore not require decoding in Unity. This will require you re-compiling your C++ code if this is an option. Please note that the audio data (in wave format) will be slightly larger in memory (than mp3).

See line 98 -> 109 of the [audio_capture.cpp](https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/blob/master/audio_capture/src/audio_capture.cpp) file for where it checks wave or mp3 formatting.

## Decode MP3 Audio in Unity

Otherwise you could try decode the mp3 data in Unity. This is most likely going to involve using an mp3 library (the first one I found was [MP3Sharp](https://github.com/ZaneDubya/MP3Sharp)). Otherwise there's a Unity asset called [uAudio](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/audio/uaudio-mp3-player-streamer-42677) that states to do realtime mp3 compression/decompression; this might be simpler than using a generic mp3 decoder as it's already been designed for Unity.

I would not recommend writing your own mp3 decoder unless just for the sake of a challenge, or for learning purposes.

---

All ideas aside, my first attempt would be to re-compile your C++ library with the argument as "wave" as stated above!

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, this is a really cool suggestion! I think it's possible to use the WAV format. Do I have to alter my unity code in any way to deal with headers or other information encoded with WAV?

Comment: Hi @NishanthJKumar, [the wave header's](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) tend to be much simpler to handle than the mp3 ones. As long as you extract the data chunk correctly this should be fine. Since I cannot see the code for how you parse the headers I cannot say, but if you are struggling to parse the wave files there are plenty of people who have built wave [parsers already](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/audio/open-wav-parser-90832). And I'm sure you will find plenty more parsers if you search :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download this .dll: https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/naudio_dll.html and import in folder Plugins
2. Download this c# script: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wks0ujanr0pm6nj/NAudioPlayer.cs?dl=0
3. Download and import this Unity Asset Store: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/runtime-file-browser-113006
4. Create a c# Script, add to a gameObject, and write this lines:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.IO;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.Runtime;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using NAudio;
    using NAudio.Wave;
    using UnityEngine.Networking;
    using SimpleFileBrowser;

    public class ReadMp3 : MonoBehaviour{
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    public Text pathText;

    private void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    public void ReadMp3Sounds()
    {
        FileBrowser.SetFilters(false, new FileBrowser.Filter("Sounds", ".mp3"));
        FileBrowser.SetDefaultFilter(".mp3");
        StartCoroutine(ShowLoadDialogCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator ShowLoadDialogCoroutine()
    {

        yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(false, null, "Select Sound", "Select");

        pathText.text = FileBrowser.Result;

        if (FileBrowser.Success)
        {
            byte[] SoundFile = FileBrowserHelpers.ReadBytesFromFile(FileBrowser.Result);
            yield return SoundFile;

            audioSource.clip = NAudioPlayer.FromMp3Data(SoundFile);
            audioSource.Play();   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just converting byte[] to float[] like that is only going to work if your data is 16 bit PCM.  if its 16bit.

If your audio really is compressed with  MPEG-1/MPEG-2 Audio Layer 3 format, getting to the stream will not be simply a matter of converting data format, it needs to be decoded (compressed first). I would try to get the sender to produce a standard, non-encoded PCM format, and your code should start to work

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that before, that's helpful! I'll see what I can do about it